# Can I retrieve an NSAttributedString in an iOS App from an archive created on OS X?

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver, nsattributedstring, macos

I have a Mac program that stores its data using NSKeyedArchiver. I'm using the same code in an iOS app to try to read in the data from the file, but it crashes when trying to decode an instance of NSAttributedString. Are the iOS and OS X versions of NSAttributedString compatible, i.e. is this a bug in iOS?

If not, is there anything I can do short of modifying the Mac app? I'd prefer not to have to do that, for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Here's the console log, less the call stack: 

`11-08-23 6:27:35.747 PM HorizonTouch: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (NSMutableParagraphStyle)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NSAttributedString may look identical on both iOS and OS X, some of
>   its properties are not.

You are correct see: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Aug/msg00479.html

NSFont vs UIFont  etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not confident in this answer without going in depth into the documentation, but whilst `NSAttributedString` may look identical on both iOS and OS X, some of its properties are not. For example, `NSString` has additions that differ both on iOS (UIStringDrawing.h) and Mac OS.

It could be to do with the decoder on iOS encountering or expecting data to be in the archive that doesn't exist. Could you paste the logs you get? Normally if a keyed archiver encounters an error it will log the problem to the console.